# how to integrate Odoo with MySQL

Tags: mysql, odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8, openerp-8

I am trying to integrate Odoo(openerp-8) with MySQL on ubuntu server, to get the database access instead of postgresql.

But I am unable to figure out the correct way to do that.

I tried this link, but it didn't help me

http://openerp-team.blogspot.de/2009/08/open-erp-server-with-mysql.html

Any better ideas on configuring odoo with MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

In Odoo apps Store One Free module Available name is **"External Database Sources"**

This module allows you to define connections to foreign databases using ODBC, Oracle Client or SQLAlchemy.

Database sources can be configured in **Settings > Configuration -> Data sources.**

Depending on the database, you need:

- to install unixodbc and python-pyodbc packages to use ODBC connections.
- to install FreeTDS driver (tdsodbc package) and configure it through ODBC to connect to Microsoft SQL Server.
- to install and configure Oracle Instant Client and cx_Oracle python library to connect to Oracle.

**Sun and Open ERP:**

The cost-effective, highly-scalable ERP solution
Read This Doc Write by Fabien Pickaers, CEO Odoo and Sun: 
http://www.epicos.com/EPCompanyProfileWeb/Content/NARITAS/Sun_and_Open_ERP.pdf

**SnipptBucket News :** http://snippetbucket.com/2014/07/openerp-mysql-odoo-mysql-synchronization-odoo-automation-openerp-automation/

**Reference Link:** https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/base_external_dbsource/